# Nesting React-Native FlatList Components and receiving both items

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to display a FlatList of items, with each item containing a FlatList of identical buttons. When one of the buttons is clicked, I want to receive both the parent FlatList item and the value the button corresponds to.

I've tried the following method with no success (timeItem is undefined):

```
timeSlotsKeyExtractor = (item, index) => item.toString();

timeSlots =
    [
        '8:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00'
    ];

renderDate = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{item.date}</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={this.timeSlots}
                keyExtractor={this.timeSlotsKeyExtractor}
                renderItem={({ timeItem }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addTimeSlot(item, timeItem)}>
                        <View><Text>{timeItem}</Text></View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
                horizontal={true} />
        </View>
    )
}

addTimeSlot(item, timeItem) {
    console.log(item)
    console.log(timeItem)
}
```

I'm aware of SectionLists, and as such also attempted to make each item of my parent FlatList an object containing both the item and the array of timeSlots, however, I wasn't sure how to go about getting the header in the renderItem section:

Screenshot of SectionList code:

```
<SectionList
    sections={this.state.weekDates}
    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
        <Text>{section.date} </Text>
    )}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text>
            {iten.date}
            {item.timeSlots}
        </Text>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```

Where am I going wrong with these approaches? I'm fairly new to React Native so there's a good chance I've missed something really simple.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a quick note, I'm not sure you need the screenshots of your code as you have the extracts below anyway.